# Truncation of a function is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $f$ be a measurable function, then the truncation of $f$

$$
 f^a(x) =
 \begin{cases}
 a & \text{if }f(x) > a \\
  f(x) & \text{if }f(x) \leq a
 \end{cases}
 $$

is a measurable function.

Im trying to solve this problem, but I am having some dificulties. For instance, I want to show $(f^a)^{-1} ((b, \infty)) $ in measurable. If $ b < a$, then $(f^a)^{-1} ((b, \infty))  = \mathbb{R}$ which is measurable. But if $b \geq a$, then $(f^a)^{-1} ((b, \infty))  = f^{-1}(-\infty, a)  \cup f^{-1}(a, \infty). $ Is this a correct solution? Im kind of unsecure about last part. Any help would greatly be welcome.

Comment: $f^a = a\chi_{(a,\infty)} + f\chi_{(-\infty,a]}$

Answer (score 2):

Write the truncation as $\min(f,a)$ and use the fact that if two functions are measurable, so is their minimum...